# Bourne Shell delete oldest file with DOY extension

Tags: date, scripting, sh

I am relatively new to bourne scripting (running on Solaris), and I am struggling with this simple problem for some reason. I am creating a script that will run in a directory, and will try to delete the files older than a certain date.

The files are of the form: log.DOY, so for example log.364, log.365, log.001, etc.

Now this would be easy if it wasn't for the pesky rollover, especially with it not always being 365 as a max (leap years).

I have debated using find -mtime, but it would be preferable to use the file extension if possible.

Do any of you scripting magicians have any suggestions?

Comment: `find -mtime` along with date stamps like YYYY-MM-DD.log is the most self-documenting solution IHMO :-) YRMV. Good luck.

Comment: Suppose you had a full set of files `log.001` through `log.366`: how would you know which was the most recent without checking the modification date anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your choice of `find` with `-mtime` is close, but there is a potentially easier way. You say you would like to remove files older than the date of some **measuring file** (say all files older than `log.287` -- including `log.287`).

`find` provides the `-newer` option that will do just that. The following is a short script that takes the measuring filename as its first argument and will print here (but you can include delete on you own) all files in that directory (non-recursively with the `-maxdepth 1` option). The `printf` operation is provided for testing to insure there are no "OOPs" accidents. Let me know if you have questions:

```
#!/bin/sh

find . -maxdepth 1 -type f ! -newer "$1" | 
while read filenm; do
    printf "%s\n" "$filenm"  ## you can add rm to remove the file
done
```

**Note:** check your version of `read`. The POSIX compliant use is shown above, but if you have the `-r` option, I would suggest its use as well.

Comment: After spending too much time banging my head against the wall with this problem, I ended up going with the -mtime route. This was primarily because I was tasked with writing a function that could have a flexible number of days worth of logs that it kept. The full line for the find command I used was:

`find ${LOG}.??? -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime +${DAYS} -exec rm {} \;`

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Solaris handy to check, but I don't think this is practical purely in shell script unless you happen to have non-standard CLI tools available (such as GNU Coreutils).

Specifically, figuring out the end-of-year wrap depends on knowing what day of the year it is right now, and I don't see a way to do that in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E29030/gentextid-483.html#scrolltoc) I can find. (It can be done in GNU `date` using `+%j` as the format.)

However, the docs do say that you should have `perl`, so I would look to use that.